# how do i parse a wiki page without taking a dump of it in python?

Tags: python

Is it possible to parse a wiki without taking its dump , as the dump itself is way too much data to handle . Thus lets say I have the url of a certain wiki and once i call it through urllib , how do I parse it and get a certain type of data using python .

here type means a certain data corresponding to a semantic match to the search that would have been done .

Comment: Can you give an example of the "certain type of data" you're trying to scrape from the page?

Comment: I don't understand your question, but if you want the source of the page you can use [pyWikipediabot](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Pywikipediabot)

Comment: lets say I am giving a search on Manchester united list of captains . So it should return me the list of captains from the wiki page

Comment: Use the answer provided by Mark Byers. If you need more detailed help, *perhaps* you should make a new question asking something like "Using BeautifulSoup, how can I get the club captains on this page into a list".

Answer (score 1):

You need an HTML parser to get the useful data from the HTML.

You can use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to help parse the HTML. I recommend that you read the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html) and have a look at the examples there.

Comment: Try this: http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest an option such as [Harvestman](http://www.harvestmanontheweb.com/)  instead, since a semantic search is likely throw multiple pages, compared to a simpler solution such as BS